# Select value in related table if it's unique or empty if it isn't with oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a PACKAGES table, and an ITEMS table. They have a one to many relationship. Also, each item belongs to a brand, which is referenced by id Given the next simplified database structure:

```
PACKAGES
package_id

PACKAGE_ITEM
package_id
item_id

ITEMS
item_id
brand_id

BRANDS
brand_id
description
```

How can I query the packages, and get a column with the brand (description) if it's unique for all its items; and empty if they don't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is aggregation with a `case` expression:

```
select pi.package_id,
       (case when min(i.brand_id) = max(i.brand_id)  -- all the same
             then min(i.brand_id)
        end) as package_brand_id
from package_item pi join
     items i
     on pi.item_id = i.item_id
group by pi.package_id;
```

If you want the description, then you would join in `brands`:

```
select pi.package_id,
       (case when min(b.description) = max(b.description)  -- all the same
             then min(b.description)
        end) as package_brand_id
from package_item pi join
     items i
     on pi.item_id = i.item_id join
     brands b
    on i.brand_id = b.brand_id
group by pi.package_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked great. However, how can i get the brand's description instead of just its id. Sorry i wasn't clear in my question, i already edited it.

Comment: It did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and group by package_id. Then with a CASE statement determine if there is only 1 brand for all the items or not:

```
select
  package_id,
  case 
    when count(distinct b.brand_id) = 1 then max(b.description) 
    else null
  end brand_description 
from packages p
inner join package_item pi on pi.package_id = p.package_id
inner join items i on i.item_id = pi.item_id
inner join brands b on b.brand_id = i.brand_id
group by p.package_id
```